# Ellipses under new keyword in c#?

Tags: c#

[image: Why is there ellipses underneath the new keyword?]

Why is there ellipses underneath the new keyword. Cant find any article on internet. There are multiple instances where i have used the new keyword in the very same method. All look normal except this one.

edit - I am using Visual Studio 2017 community edition. Developing for UWP. The code runs fine and it is not shown as an error. pressing ctrl+. gives nothing.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you considered hovering the cursor over it? I'd expect some kind of tooltip or popup would be provided to you.

Comment: Do you have further analysis extensions installed, like ReSharper? Is there a tooltip when you hover over the ellipsis with your mouse cursor?

Comment: @ChrisPickford VS 2017 Community Edition. I'll edit the question and mention additional details.

Comment: Right click on the three dots, then choose "Quick Actions and Refactorings" (or press CTRL + .) and it'll show you what it's suggesting.

Comment: One reason the `new` might be marked like that is if you set properties on the object in the next lines. It would be making a suggestion to use object initialization syntax.

Comment: @Equalsk That worked. Apparently its a new feature of VS2017 and suggest alternate ways of creating new instances of objects(in this particular case, using grouped object instantiation). Weird, I couldnt find this on the documentation.
Thanks.

Comment: No problem, in which case @RenéVogt answer appears to be the correct one.

Comment: Also, consider using implicit typing here. Convention prefers  a `var` when the type of the variable is directly stated in the declaration line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's telling you that you can use an [object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers). So if you have code like

```
FolderPicker pickFolder = new FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
folderPicker.CommitButtonText = "Take it!";
```

Visual Studio recommends to use this

```
FolderPicker pickFolder = new FolderPicker
{
    SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop,
    CommitButtonText = "Take it!"
};
```

instead.

Comment: Slightly separate topic, but is there any benefit to using the object initializer? Or is it just a personal preference up to the developer?

Comment: @NicholasV. no performance differences, just improves maintainability/readability.

Comment: @NicholasV.: I believe its just syntactic sugar. The actual compiled code will be the same. I think.

Comment: @NicholasV. afaik it's only syntactical sugar, and if there are benefits than surely not in performance.